How to optimize the prompt and make it a single prompt to reduce the api request
I am using a multiple prompts to fetch the answer from the openai gpt 4 model. How can I optimize it to make it a single APi request instead of hitting the API multiple times
static async Task ProcessAndStorePrompts(IConfiguration configuration, string jsonData, string tenantId, Database databaseHandler)
{
    var prompts = new Dictionary<string, Action<OpenAIModel, string>>()
{
    { "What is the total profit? Give the overview.", (OpenAIModel, answer) => OpenAIModel.Profit = answer },
    { "What is the total cost of sales? Give the overview.", (OpenAIModel, answer) => OpenAIModel.NetIncome = answer },
    { "What is the total administrative cost? Give detailed overview of each and every parameters of administrative cost.", (OpenAIModel, answer) => OpenAIModel.Overheads = answer },
    { "What is the total operational cost? Give the overview.", (OpenAIModel, answer) => OpenAIModel.Expenses = answer },
    { "What is the total income? Give the overview.", (OpenAIModel, answer) => OpenAIModel.Revenue = answer }
};

    // Get current month and year
    string currentMonth = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM yyyy");

    // Create an OpenAI model instance
    var aiModel = new OpenAIModel
    {
        Tenant = tenantId,
        Month = DateTime.Now,

    };

    foreach (var prompt in prompts)
    {
        string answer = await AskQuestionAboutJsonAsync(configuration, prompt.Key, jsonData);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(answer))
        {
            // Assign the answer to the appropriate field in the model
            prompt.Value(aiModel, answer);
        }
    }

    // Store the data in the database
    databaseHandler.JsontoAI(aiModel);
}


What's the reason you want a single API request?

If it "works" then SO is probably not the correct SE site. Is there any (code-related) problem about it that makes it unusable to you? The Stackoverflow community will rather not reduce your API costs for free, you see? That's what consultants are for.

my question meant - suppose if I have 10 files, then as per my prompt there are 5 prompts so 105 will be 50 API hit. so i want to make a single prompt which will get hit only once, in that case my api call will be 101 = 10 . Anyways I did that and is working fine
